# How to generate Java crash log on native code abort?

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

In Oracle's Java 8 on Linux 64-bit, when a segmentation fault occurs, I get a useful log of information to standard output:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ff98a6d3467, pid=21380, tid=140709678728960
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_40-b25) (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.40-b25 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [photo-collection.so+0x1e467]  photocollection::PhotoDataGrabber::workerRoutine()+0x87
```

Especially useful is the native code location (eg `photo-collection.so+0x1e467`).

However, when a C++ exception is thrown, I see only the print-out from the C++ runtime, and the JVM gives no information.

Is there a way to produce the JVM crash log information for a C++ exception as well?

Comment: Are you sure this is all that is printed out. Perhaps the stack trace is there and you missed it ;)

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior?  The JVM might not be throwing exceptions.  I believe If you want to log it on the JVM side then you just have to send it back.